# How do I write a Select statement in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do I select date of birth from a drop-down list in selenium web-driver? Here is what i have tried:

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver. findElement(By.id("month"))).click();
```

Comment: How do you want to select, by index/by value/ by text?

Answer (score 0):

First the drop down element should be selected

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")))
```

Now, any of the select method can be used like

```
oSelect.selectByVisibleText("February") // or
oSelect.selectByIndex(1)                // or
oSelect.selectByValue(value attribute of the element to be selected)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.